# How to make fixtures updateable in Rails' tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, fixtures

Below I listed some code from simple Rails application. The test listed below fails in last line, because the **updated_at** field of the post is not changed within the update action of PostController in this test. Why?

This behaviour seems to me a little strange, because standard timestamps are included in Post model, *live testing* on local server shows that this field is actually updated after returning from update action and first assertion is fulfilled thus it shows the update action went ok.

How can I make fixtures *updateable* in above meaning?

```
# app/controllers/post_controller.rb
def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
    redirect_to @post     # Update went ok!
  else
    render :action => "edit"
  end
end

# test/functional/post_controller_test.rb
test "should update post" do
  before = Time.now
  put :update, :id => posts(:one).id, :post => { :content => "anothercontent" }
  after = Time.now

  assert_redirected_to post_path(posts(:one).id)     # ok
  assert posts(:one).updated_at.between?(before, after), "Not updated!?" # failed
end

# test/fixtures/posts.yml
one:
  content: First post
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
posts(:one)
```

That means "fetch the fixture named ":one" in posts.yml.  That's never going to change during a test, barring some extremely weird and destructive code that has no place in sane tests.

What you want to do is check the object that the controller is assigning.

```
post = assigns(:post)
assert post.updated_at.between?(before, after)
```

Answer (score 1):

On a side note if you were using shoulda (http://www.thoughtbot.com/projects/shoulda/) it would look like this:

```
context "on PUT to :update" do
    setup do 
        @start_time = Time.now
        @post = posts(:one)
        put :update, :id => @post.id, :post => { :content => "anothercontent" } 
    end
    should_assign_to :post
    should "update the time" do
        @post.updated_at.between?(@start_time, Time.now)
    end
end
```

Shoulda is awesome.

Comment: Indeed.  Shoulda is great stuff.